# Why are not ALL abelian groups $G\simeq \mathbb Z_{n_1} \times \mathbb Z_{n_2} \times \cdots\times \mathbb Z_{n_s}$ where $|G| = n_1 n_2 \cdots n_s$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I'm in the middle of reading this text, but something bugs me. That is:

> Why are not ALL abelian groups $G\simeq \mathbb Z_{n_1} \times \mathbb Z_{n_2} \times \cdots\times \mathbb Z_{n_s}$ where $|G| = n_1 n_2 \cdots n_s$?

For example for $|G| = 180$, the abelian groups are: $Z_{180}$, $Z_{90} \times Z_2$, $Z_{60} \times Z_3$ and $Z_{30} \times Z_6$.

Why is not for example $Z_{18} \times Z_{10}$?

Here is the text:

[image]

Comment: Is your question "why doesn't the theorem apply to abelian groups which are not finitely generated?" or is it "why don't all abelian groups have the form $\mathbb{Z}_k$ for some integer $k$"?

Comment: All finite abelian groups *do* have that form. Just what is your question, really?

Comment: It is still hard to understand what you are really are trying to ask. My guess is that maybe you are asking if $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ should be isomorphic. Note that in the first all elements are their own inverse, but in the second $1+1=2\neq 0$.

Comment: I just added more clarification to my question.

Comment: I see now. Ok, $\mathbb{Z}_{18}\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is a finitely generated Abelian group and that product is valid. However, it has other factorizations. The Theorem says that it has a factorization in the form that is written there. In this case it would be $\mathbb{Z}_{90}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Yes, but why for example $Z_{18} \times Z_{10}$ cannot?

Comment: It can. The theorem doesn't forbid factorizations. It asserts the existence of a particular factorization. Now, because that particular form of a factorization always exists and is unique as stated, then you can use that form as a 'canonical form'. If you have two finitely generated Abelian groups that you want to test if they are isomorphic, then you can bring them both to their canonical factorization and just compare the factors.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Ah, I see that's where I missed. Would you mind to write it as the answer? Thanks.

Comment: It is similar to the situation in the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. You can factor the natural number $180$ as $2\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 2$, or as $18\cdot 10$, or as $1\cdot 180$. But there is always a factorization into powers of increasing primes $2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5$, which is unique in the sense that any other product of powers of increasing primes that results in $180$ will have the same sequence of primes and of exponents.

Comment: Since $9,2$ are coprime, $Z_{18}\cong Z_9\times Z_2$. Since $9,10$ are coprime, $Z_{90}\cong Z_9\times Z_{10}$. Therefore $Z_{18}\times Z_{10}\cong Z_{9}\times Z_{2}\times Z_{10}\cong Z_{90}\times Z_2$ which is on your list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're just not.  Groups of the form $\mathbb Z_n$ are *cyclic*: if you keep adding the class of $1$ to itself, you get everything in the group.  Example: $\mathbb Z_4$ the elements are:

$$1$$

$$1+1$$

$$1+1+1$$

$$1+1+1+1$$

A group like $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ does not have an element like that.  The elements are $(0,0);(1,0);(0,1);(1,1)$ and if you continually add any of these elements to itself, you will not get all the elements of the group.  So $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ cannot be isomorphic to a group like $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: Sorry, there's mistake in my question. It should be: why is not ALL abelian groups $Z_{n_1} \times Z_{n_2} \times ... \times Z_{n_s} \cong G$ where $\mid G \mid = n_1 n_2 ... n_s$?

May you re-update the answer?

Comment: My answer was in the form of an example illustrating the general principle.  Not all abelian groups of the form $\prod \mathbb Z_{n_i}$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{n_1 \cdots n_s}$ because not all of them are cyclic.

Comment: Anw just realized that isn't it according the theory $Z_4$ could be factored into $Z_4$ and $Z_2 \times Z_2$?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ as an additive group. It's abelian, but it simply is not of the form $Z_{n_1} \times Z_{n_2} \times ... \times Z_{n_s}$. (If it were of that form, it would be a finite group.)

Consider the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ as an additive group. It's abelian, but it simply is not of the form $\mathbb{Z}^r\times Z_{n_1} \times Z_{n_2} \times ... \times Z_{n_s}$. (If it were of that form, then either $r=0$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ would be finite, or $r\geq1$ and  you couldn't divide certain elements like $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ in half.)

Comment: I think it's not immediately obvious that $\mathbb{Q}$ can't be written in the form guaranteed by the structure theorem. I think a more clear example would be $\mathbb{R}$ considered as an additive group. It has no hope of being isomorphic to something of that form since it's of a strictly larger cardinality. Never mind, I see you clarified with an edit. I'm leaving this comment here, though, since it may still be instructive to the OP.

Comment: @alex.jordan Sorry, there's mistake in my question. It should be: why is not ALL abelian groups $Z_{n_1} \times Z_{n_2} \times ... \times Z_{n_s} \cong G$ where $\mid G \mid = n_1 n_2 ... n_s$?

May you re-update the answer?